# How do I get Monterey to "forget" an external monitor that will not be connected again (anytime soon)?

Tags: display, monterey

I had been using 2 external monitors from my MacBook. I want to repurpose one of them to use with another MacBook (and there it is working fine). However, I want to tell the first MacBook to not assume that that monitor is there: in the system "Display" preferences, it's still there. I wouldn't really care at all except that I keep losing my mouse off the left edge of the screen.

Comment: I assume a reboot didn‘t solve this? Is the monitor cable still plugged in? Did you try to unplug all monitor cables and reboot?

Comment: I should try a reboot. No, the cable is plugged into the other macbook. Thanks!

Comment: @nohillside yea that did it. I should have guessed :)  Thanks again.

Comment: Are these displays close to each other? Are the Macs using the same Apple ID? It sounds like Universal Control.

Answer (score 2):

Things to try

- Unplug *all* monitor cables
- Reboot